# How to add a namespace to a soap method call using the soap plugin with node.js

Tags: node.js, wcf, soap

I would like to send a position to a WCF soap web service from node.js

I am using the soap node.js plugin and calling the remote method like this:

```
       var localisationMessage = {
            BlackboxNumber: adc,
            Heading: heading,
            Kilomettrage: kilomettrage,
            Latitude: latitude,
            Longitude: longitude,
            PositionDate: '2014-01-28T10:28:09.859225+01:00', //date.toISOString(),
            Satelite: satelite,
            Speed: speed,
        }

        var args = {
            mess: localisationMessage
        }

        console.dir(args);

        self.soap_client.SendLocalisation(args, function(err, result) {
             ...
        }
```

Using tcpdump, this is what is sent to the service:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"  
               xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" 
               xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" 
               xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract">
<soap:Header></soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
<tns:SendLocalisation xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<tns:mess>
<tns:BlackboxNumber>521020</tns:BlackboxNumber>
<tns:Heading>0</tns:Heading>
<tns:Kilomettrage>0</tns:Kilomettrage>
<tns:Latitude>50.82401</tns:Latitude>
<tns:Longitude>4.30416</tns:Longitude>
<tns:PositionDate>2014-01-28T10:28:09.859225+01:00</tns:PositionDate>
<tns:Satelite>7</tns:Satelite>
<tns:Speed>0</tns:Speed>
</tns:mess>
</tns:SendLocalisation>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

With the code above, I receive an answer false 
What I should send is this (tcpdump trace using C#) :

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body><SendLocalisation xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<mess xmlns:a="http://my_webservice_namespace" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<a:BlackboxNumber>358696048896800</a:BlackboxNumber>
<a:Heading>0</a:Heading>
<a:Kilomettrage>0</a:Kilomettrage>
<a:Latitude>50</a:Latitude>
<a:Longitude>3</a:Longitude>
<a:PositionDate>2014-01-28T10:28:09.859224+01:00</a:PositionDate>
<a:Satelite>7</a:Satelite>
<a:Speed>0</a:Speed>
</mess>
</SendLocalisation>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

As you can see the main difference is that all the parameters of the soap call are in the namespace a which is not defined when I use the service from node.js

How can I define this namespace during the soap method call on node.js ?

Comment: I set a soap namespace in my WCF client with Java, but I'm using MimeHeaders. It's not what you're doing, but if you'd like to see what I'm doing, I'd be happy to post the code. Just let me know.

Comment: @Brian it is probably not necessary, my problem is with the soap node.js module.